Switch off headset mode in Ubuntu 24.04
Since Ubuntu 24.04, I can't find a way to switch off headset mode of my Bose headphones.
In older Ubuntu releases, in Settings, I could choose to use the headphones as A2DP or headset mode. However, I don't have this option in Ubuntu 24.04 anymore. I only get a "handsfree" option and if I select that, I can only switch between headset mode codecs.

(home is the name of my headphones)

So I think this was a bug. Normally the "Output Device" selection box should have two entries for my headphones. One named "Headphone" and one named "Headset". However, for me it only showed the "Headset" variant.
I fixed it by unpairing my headphones with my laptop by clicking "Forget Device" in the Bluetooth settings. After I paired them again, now it shows two entries for my headphones in "Output Device"

